# Google Youtube API v3 (using public API key) not working on server but it works on localhost

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have been struggling with this problem for weeks. I have created public API key in https://console.developers.google.com. My application is written in PHP and uses google-api-php-client. I have added IP addresses of my localhost and public server in whitelist in google console.

My application only fetches list of YouTube videos from some chanell and displays them. Everything works fine on localhost but on server it causes error

```
(403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

Strange is that immediatly after launching application on a server it worked fine. But now it is broken.

Edit:
It works fine on subdomain too.... Could be a problem in DNS settings?

Do you have any idea what the problem is?
Thanks

Comment: try removing $client->setDeveloperKey($key); if it works, i will explain why it does so

Comment: It didn't work. Google says Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.

Comment: are you using OAuth2 ?

Comment: No I am using public API key. I think it is unnecessary. Only thing I need is to fetch list of public videos from one channel. Nothing more.

As far as I know OAuth is needed when I want e.g. upload video.

Comment: was there ever a resolution for this? I'm trying to develop something on localhost but can't get my API key to work.

Answer (score 0):

The fix had to do with `cURL`, and I really can not explain why it did work,  it's something related with `SSL`.

Basically, you need to turn of `SSL` verification, by using

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```