# YouTube API works on localhost, fails on server

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-data-api

I've been writing code to grab stats from the YouTube Data API v3. Everything was working just fine while testing on localhost. But when I uploaded the code to my server, the page wouldn't load at all.

There weren't any errors showing either, whether from php or in the html source. Nothing.

This is where the code breaks:

```
function ytgetvidnfo($inservice, $yid)
{
    $response = $inservice->videos->listVideos('snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics',
                array('id' => $yid ));
    return $response;
}
$searchResponse = ytgetvidnfo($service, $ytl);
```

I tried replacing that with the code given by YouTube themselves on Google APIs, just in case I'd messed something up:

```
function videosListById($service, $part, $params) 
{
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->videos->listVideos(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

videosListById($service,'snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics',array('id' => $ytl));
```

With both of these I get the same result: works fine on localhost, but breaks on the server. The HTML source shows it stops right after the `<BODY>` tag.

I could pinpoint the issue even further by issuing:

`print_r($client);` ==> works on localhost & online

`print_r($service);` ==> only works on localhost

So it looks like it's not managing to grab the video information... but why?

I noticed somebody else asked a similar question in 2014, but got no definitive answer:

[Google Youtube API v3 (using public API key) not working on server but it works on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779960/google-youtube-api-v3-using-public-api-key-not-working-on-server-but-it-works)

Comment: What lib/client are you using?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to mention that, didn't I? I'm using google-api-php-client-2.2.1.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.